# How to get the end week of a DATETIME column in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, week-number

I am using MySQL and having issues getting the end of the week date from a DATETIME column, where the end of the week is considered Sunday,

My table looks like this:

| Unique_ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-07-13 17:03:31.035 |
| 456 | 2021-01-01 15:02:19.029 |
| 789 | 2020-08-02 18:07:14.011 |

I am needing to get the week for each line where the week ends on Sunday. The time isn't needed. So the end result for 2021-01-01 would show 2021-01-03 since that week ends on Sunday. Does anyone know what function to use for this?

Comment: `SELECT DATE(datetime_column) + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(datetime_column) DAY`

Comment: @Akina this worked! Thank you so much. I hope I'm not asking too much, but can you describe what INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY and then the DAY function are doing? I don't quite understand.

Comment: `WEEKDAY` function returns the number of DOW. `6 - WEEKDAY(datetime_column)` is an arithmetic expression which calculates the amount of the days till Sunday. `+ INTERVAL xx DAY` adds this days amount to the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an elaboration (I hope) of Akina's suggestion in the comment:

```
SELECT *,
       dt + INTERVAL 6 DAY add6 /*add 6 day ahead*/,
       DAYNAME(dt + INTERVAL 6 DAY) dn6 /*6 day ahead dayname*/,
       dt + INTERVAL (6 - wkd) DAY nxtsun /*add 6 day ahead then subtract weekday value from date column*/,
       DAYNAME(dt + INTERVAL (6 - wkd) DAY) nxtsundn
FROM
(SELECT *, 
       DATE(date) dt,
       DAYNAME(date) dn,
       WEEKDAY(date) wkd
FROM mytable) A;
```

Let's take the second row from your data sample to illustrate what is happening. The base query above:

```
SELECT *, 
       DATE(date) dt,
       DAYNAME(date) dn,
       WEEKDAY(date) wkd
FROM mytable
```

Will return the following.

| Unique_ID | Date | dn | wkd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | 2021-01-01 15:02:19 | Friday | 4 |

Note that the `WEEKDAY(date)` (aliased as `wkd` in the table) returns 4. Which means it's `Friday`. [According to the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday), `WEEKDAY()` function returns like the following:

```
0 = Monday
1 = Tuesday
2 = Wednesday
3 = Thursday
4 = Friday
5 = Saturday
6 = Sunday
```

Adding 6 day interval to the current `WEEKDAY()` result goes to the day before next same dayname of the current `date` value. So `WEEKDAY(2021-01-01)` which is on `Friday`, becomes `2021-01-07` which is on `Thursday` after being added with 6 day ahead. With a subtraction of the pervious obtained `WEEKDAY()` value, the operation becomes `DATE + INTERVAL (6 - 4) DAY`, which effectively becomes `DATE + INTERVAL 2 DAY`.

[Here's a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fddc73c2dbd0245e01d5960c1478f8da)